# Detect scroll event in UIScrollView and send to UITableView or other UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, events, ipad, uiscrollview, touch

I have a problem. I have a UISCrollView and I need obtain the event when the user touch the scrollView and send to other ScrollView o TableView these scrollMove.

How I can send the move capture in my ScrollView to other ScrollView or TableView for make these movement.

For simple touches I use touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded, but the touchesMove don't work in UIScrollView and can't send these movement to other ScrollView or TableView.

I put a example. I need send the scroll event in secondView scrollView conflict area to the tableView for make scroll in tableView.

```
     First View
     -----------------------------
     -         -                 - 
     -         -                 - 
     -    T    -                 - 
     -    A    -                 - 
     -    B    -                 - 
     -    L    -                 - 
     -    E    -                 - 
     -    V    -                 - 
     -    I    -                 - 
     -    E    -                 - 
     -    W    -                 - 
     -         -                 - 
     -         -                 - 
     -----------------------------


    Second View  --> ##### is the ScrollView area on tableView FirstView
     -----------------------------
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######   SCROLL        - 
     -   -######    VIEW         - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -   -######                 - 
     -----------------------------

     ###### I need scroll on this area and send the moviment to back tableView.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your question is incredibly hard to understand. Please rephrase.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand but let me try to summerize: you are trying to take the touch events from a UIScrollView denoted by the # marks and send those touch events to a UITablView to make the UITableView scroll a proportional amount as the UISrollView?

Answer (score 5):

HI,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and u can the touches inside this method

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)touch
{ 
CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
}
```

Copy of ([Scroll View Touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216413/uiscrollview-touch-events/5216518#5216518))