# UIScrollview getting touch events

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitouch

How can I detect touch points in my `UIScrollView`? The touches delegate methods are not working.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Set up a tap gesture recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and you will get the touches in:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! 
And all these posts about subclassing UIScrollView, pah!

Comment: I used your code. but due to UITapGestureRecognizer, button click on scroll view is not working..?

Comment: @Hercules add controller as delegate to recognizer and use this function: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) return YES;
    else return NO;

}

Comment: @yuf and Hercules, note that iOS 5 and 6 currently differentiate on whether the contentOffset is calculated before receiving touch. Apple decided to change this and break all custom code for who knows why. 5 doesn't, 6 does. Why do this!!? Argh. Should help other coders with no button receiving input problem).

Comment: In Xcode 5 IB (Interface Builder) drag on "Tap Gesture Recognizer" object to ScrollView. Then Control Drag from ScrollView to implementation code (*.m) to add a tap gesture method.

Comment: @yuf may you add your comment as an answer. It helped me.

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own UIScrollview subclass and then you can implement the following:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 

{

NSLog(@"DEBUG: Touches began" );

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"DEBUG: Touches cancelled");

    // Will be called if something happens - like the phone rings

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"DEBUG: Touches moved" );

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"DEBUG: Touches ending" );
    //Get all the touches.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    //Number of touches on the screen
    switch ([allTouches count])
    {
        case 1:
        {
            //Get the first touch.
            UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

            switch([touch tapCount])
            {
                case 1://Single tap

                    break;
                case 2://Double tap.

                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about the points inside the scrollview then you can hook with the delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and inside the method, read the property:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint contentOffset
```

from the scrollView to get the coordination.

Comment: hi, i don't want to get touches when the scrollview Dragging, i need like **TouchesBegan**

Answer (score 0):

**This works also on touch down event.**

In the currently as correct marked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216518/) you can get a `touch point` only at a "Tap" event. This event seems only to fire on "finger up" not on down.

From the comment of yuf in the same answer you can get the `touch point` from the underlying view also within the `UIScrollView`.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  return TRUE; // since we're only interested in the touchPoint
}
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer?language=objc) the `gestureRecognizer` does:

> Ask the delegate if a gesture recognizer should receive an object representing a touch.

which means to me that I can decide if a `gestureRecognizer` should recieve a touch or not.