# iPhone - UIScrollView... detecting the coordinates of a touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIScrollview getting touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216413/uiscrollview-getting-touch-events)

Is it possible to detect where in a UIScrollView the finger touched?

I mean, suppose the user uses his finger in this way: taps and scroll, lifts the finger and again, taps and scroll, etc. Is it possible to know the CGPoint where the taps happened in relation to the self.view the scroller is in? The scroller occupies the whole self.view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with gesture recognizers. For detect single tap location use `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)] autorelease];
[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{ 
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:myScrollView];
    CGPoint tapPointInView = [myScrollView convertPoint:tapPoint toView:self.view];
}
```

To convert that `tapPoint` to self.view you can use [`convertPoint:toView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:) method in UIView class

Comment: nope. tapAction is just triggered if I tap and don't scroll. If I do like I said, tap, scroll, lift finger, tap, scroll, lift finger, etc., no tap is ever detected. No tap is ever detected also if the scroller is also scrolling after a big swipe. The scroller has to be still and one dry tap has to be made, for this to work.

Comment: There are a lot of other gesture recognizers - UIPanGestureRecognizer , UIPinchGestureRecognizer, UISwipeGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer. Moreover, you can create custom recognizer to detect very complex touches. I gave the more popular example with simple touch.

Comment: @RubberDuck Have you figured out this? I'm on the same boat... I'm working on a UICollectionView, I want detect if finger touch is on the cell view

Comment: I've `UIkit.framework` under my frameworks but I cannot find out `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When I try to write `UITapGestureRecognizer` it gives me error as not found.

Comment: @beryllium Why you won't just do [sender locationInView: myScrollView] ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [touchesBegan:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder)  You will get a NSSet of [UITouch's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch), and a UITouch contains a locationInView: method that should return the CGPoint of the touch.

Comment: In this case you need to subclass UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be able to subclass it and look at touchesBegan.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW1

Comment: it is not that easy. TouchesBegan just detects a touch if the scrollview is still if it is moving already and I touch it, touchesBegan will not detect anything.

Answer (score -1):

You could find the location in the view and add the scroll ofset to it. Now, your next problem is that `-(void)touchesBegan:touches:event` won't be called because the events will be sent to your scrollview. This can be fixed by subclassing your UIScrollView and have the scrollview send the touch events to the next responder (your view).

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Position of touch in view
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    // Scroll view offset
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    // Result
    CGPoint scrollViewPoint = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y + offset.y);
    NSLog(@"Touch position in scroll view: %f %f", scrollViewPoint.x, scrollViewPoint.y);
}
```

Comment: nope. touchesBegan is just triggered if I tap and don't scroll. If I do like I said, tap, scroll, lift finger, tap, scroll, lift finger, etc., no tap is ever detected. No tap is ever detected also if the scroller is also scrolling after a big swipe. The scroller has to be still and one dry tap has to be made, for this to work. It is not easy as it seems.