# Is there a way to detect or get a notification when user swipes to scroll?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to detect or get a notification when user swipes to scroll?
I am using 
    (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *) scrollView; 
but i am getting error:
 Use of undeclared identifier 'scrollViewDidScroll'
can anyone tell me why?

@daf & H2SO3

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setting the color of this view
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //creating scrollview controller
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView          alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,(self.view.frame.size.height)/3)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3200, 4000);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    //creating uiimage

    UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wallpapers1.jpg"];

    //creating image view

    UIImageView* imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];

    imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(1241,0,image1.size.width,image1.size.height);

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
    // [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(1200, 0, 100, 100) animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    ScrollDirection scrollDirection;
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionRight;
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionLeft;

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

    // do whatever you need to with scrollDirection here.
}
```

Comment: No, not in the lack of any code.

Comment: Post more code for us to actually be able to help you

Comment: Set up a tap gesture recognizer. 



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216413/uiscrollview-getting-touch-events/5216518#5216518

Comment: Where in the posted code are you getting the error?

Comment: @STANGMMX Thanks for you concern, but can you tell me whats wrong with  scrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: @rrnaddy In the last function and i get the error Use of undeclared identifier 'scrollViewDidScroll'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong delegate method. Try using this one

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Comment: I m using the same delegate method  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: How is this different than the posted code? The argument name can be anything.