# not getting touches from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have subclassed UIScrollView and implemented 
`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` 
method in it.

But Nothing happens when click or hold the scroll view!

Edit: I also need to use touchesEnded method

Comment: Can you please provide more important. Are you creating your UIScrollView through Storyboard? Make sure touch events are enabled.

Comment: no i am not using storyboard or .xib files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216413/uiscrollview-getting-touch-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think UIScrollView has two gesture recognizer. They are responsible for handling touch sequences, so they swallow the touch events.

Use scrollView delegate methods to handle drag gestures or the

touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:

method to handle scrollview content touches and

touchesShouldCancelInContentView:

to cancel it.

As alternative you can manipulate the panGesture recognizer of the scrollView to pass the event to the next responser.

Comment: That' what I was looking for! Does UIScrollView have a method which gets called when touches ends?

Comment: Yes, but as i told the event call gets intercepted by the gestures. Use touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView: to return YES for your special views, so they will get the touchedBegan/ended events

Answer (score 1):

In your subclass of UIScrollView override the hitTest method like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UIView *result = nil;
  for (UIView *child in self.subviews)
    if ([child pointInside:point withEvent:event])
      if ((result = [child hitTest:point withEvent:event]) != nil)
        break;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Ya i had used that before. Anyways, could you explain the code?

Comment: [hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) "Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point."

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using scrollview as a subview.So in that case you can use gesture coz same problem i've face it.

You can do using `UITapGestureRecognizer`  like this ...

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
   gr.delegate = self;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
}
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // do here whatever you wanna ..........
}
```

Comment: I am not using viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Used `LongPressedGestureRecognizer`. The action method keeps getting called till the user holds the view. From that i can figure out the state of the gestureRecognizer (`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `...Ended`, `...Cancelled`)